# Revert a GitHub PR to a particular commit

Tags: git, github

I've created a new GitHub PR for branch `new-feature`, it has 10 commits.

I want to revert it to be at the 5th commit.

What is the proper workflow?

**Notes:**

If I'm on `new-feature` and use `git reset --hard <sha-of-my-5th-commit>`, this will just move my local state back. I'm not sure how to affect github's history with this

Comment: Have you used `cherry-pick`? It allows you to pick certain commits and apply them to your branch.

Comment: Here is an example of that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20698614/multiple-commits-cherry-picking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please be careful with hard resets and push force. You should back up stuff before resetting. But,

After `git reset --hard <sha-of-my-5th-commit>` you can run

```
git push -f
```

to overwrite the remote branch.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to actually record the history after a reset with a differentiating commit or if force push is disabled, use the following commands:

After `git reset --hard <sha-of-my-5th-commit>`:

```
  git reset --soft FETCH_HEAD
  git commit -m "describe the changes you reset"
  git push
```